# What does the command ps -o <arg> exactly do?

Tags: unix

I have already checked man pages about usage of `ps -o` but did not understand. When I executed command `ps -o pid`, I got this result : -

```
$>ps -o pid
     PID
 6029508
29491290
```

I want to know what does the command `ps -o pid -o cmd -u <username>` do?

Answer (score 1):

The POSIX specification for [`ps`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ps.html) tells you what the `-o` option does.  So will the man-page on your system.

Basically, it controls which columns of output appear.

```
$ ps -o pid
  PID
  297
  303
  314
  321
  329
$ ps -o pid -o command
  PID COMMAND
  297 -sh
  303 -sh
  314 -sh
  321 -sh
  329 -sh
$
```

A dreadfully unexciting command list - sorry about that.  Note that POSIX defines `comm` and `args`; on Mac OS X, `command` is recognized as well, but `cmd` was not.

The `-u user` option restricts the list of processes to those owned by the named user.